# Postfix with php mail function - Getting a 504

Tags: php, email, postfix-mta

Running on Ubuntu nginx with postfix mail_version = 3.3.2

I am trying to send emails via php mail function as such:

```
<?php
$to      = 'me@gmail.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: support@xxxx.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

However, I get a 504 with nothing in the php/nginx log

This is my post-fix conf

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_un$
myhostname = name_of_my_host.linode.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = , $myhostname, Ubuntu-xxxx, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost =
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_protocols = all
maillog_file = /var/log/postfix.log
```

Any guidance would be useful.

Comment: did you check logs in /var/log/postfix.log? what does postfix logs says?

Comment: Hi Mamoun. The postfix log is empty. However the mail log doesn't provide any information regarding this. I can send email from the server but not via php though.

Comment: I manage to remove the 504 by adding this line in my php.ini: sendmail_path = /etc/postfix . However mail doesn't arrive at destination. I will check how I can get the log to work.

Comment: check this for logs configuration: http://www.postfix.org/MAILLOG_README.html if you still use postfix, and one more thing usually mail logs are in /var/logs/mail.log try to check that out too.